# How to run different ENTRYPOINT commands in Dockerfile for different build environments?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Right now I have a single `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-slim

WORKDIR /

COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY ./dist ./dist

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT npm start
# ENTRYPOINT npm run dev
```

You see that I have 2 options for the `ENTRYPOINT`. When I'm developing, I need it to run `npm run dev`. When I'm deploying it, I need it to run `npm start`.

How can I do this while keeping a single `Dockerfile` file?

Is there a way to pass some kind of build arguments / ENV variables? How do people usually handle this?

Here is how I run it:

```
docker run hello-world:latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD`, you can easily override it at the `docker run` command line:

```sh
# No ENTRYPOINT
CMD npm start
```

```sh
# The command after the image name overrides CMD
docker run hello-world:latest npm run dev
```

(There is a `docker run --entrypoint` option, but its syntax winds up being pretty awkward.)

> How do people usually handle this?

I do as much development as I can outside of Docker.  It's very rare for me to run into problems that are sensitive to exact interpreter versions, and the host environment often doesn't make a difference either.  This is doubly true for front-end applications where the only thing that happens in Docker is the application build; all of the runtime and I/O happens in the end user's browser.

```sh
# Without Docker
npm run dev
npm run test
npm run lint

# Ship it
docker build -t my/image .
docker run -p 3000:3000 my/image
```

If at all possible, run the same image in test and production environments.  Do not overwrite the code in the image with a bind mount or other volume mount.

Comment: You are definitely right. I shouldn't be developing with a running docker container. There absolutely no need for that. I should just run the `express` server locally and it should behave very much the same. Thank you for all the recommendations.

Comment: If you want to do development outside but run the app inside container environment, you can create a bind mount volume.